# Row orthogonaly theorem for irreducible character table

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let A = $ \begin{bmatrix} \chi_{\phi^1}(g \in C_1) & \chi_{\phi^2}(g \in C_1) & \dots & \chi_{\phi^n}(g \in C_1)\\ \chi_{\phi^1}(g \in C_2) & \chi_{\phi^2}(g \in C_2) & \dots &\chi_{\phi^n}(g \in C_1)\\ \vdots & \vdots & \dots & \vdots \\ \chi_{\phi^1}(g \in C_n) &\chi_{\phi^2}(g \in C_n) & \dots & \chi_{\phi^n}(g \in C_n)  
\end{bmatrix}$

be the character table for a group representation, where $C$ is a conjugacy class of $G$ and $ \phi^i$ is the $i$'th irreducible representation.

The **columns** of $A$ is orthonormal with respect to the inner product $(\chi_{\phi^i}, \chi_{\phi^j}) = \frac{1}{G} \sum_{g \in G} \chi_{\phi^i}(g) \chi_{\phi^j}(g)^{\ast} = \delta_{ij}$.

This proof is rather long, so we assume that the statement above is true. From this, how do I show that the **rows** of A satisfy $$ (\psi_i , \psi_j) = \sum_\chi \chi(g \in c_i) \chi(g \in c_j) =\begin{cases} \frac{|G|}{|C|} \quad \text{If i = j}\\ 0 \quad \text{else}\end{cases}$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you are calling rows columns. Doesn't this do the trick https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Column_orthogonality_theorem

Comment: Ya, but I was a bit confused by it, since they write the character table as the transposed as what im used to, so I couldnt really follow.

Comment: I have never in a long life seen the character table with the characters across the top and the classes down the side: until today.

Comment: Ah, you mean classes $ \rightarrow $ and character $ \downarrow $? If it is the way you say, I rather learn to view the character table that way!